# Can't save multiple selections in select list - asp.net core web app razor pages

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Here I am able to bind the multi-select select list on the create page.

```
<select id="multiple" asp-for="SecurityLog.Officer" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Officer">
</select>

public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
{                    
     ViewData["Officer"] = new SelectList(_context.Officer.Where(a => a.Active == "Y"), "ID", "FullName");

     return Page();
}
```

The biggest problem I'm having is that I am trying to edit/post values and there's no direct field to bind to in my model.

[image: Multi-select binding]

I have found a good example here, but it only shows you how to save 1 selection.
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists

My SecurityLog Model has this

```
public virtual Officer Officer { get; set; }
```

My Officer Model has this

```
namespace SecurityCore.Models
{
    public class Officer
    {
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Officer's First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Officer's Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Officer's Name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Active { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

I do not have a SecurityLogOfficer Model.  Do I need one?

**And here is my database schema and sample results**

[image: Sql Database Schema]

Any assistance would be appreciated!

*** UPDATE ***

Thank you for your suggestion to bind to a list and change the asp-for to that list.  Here is my updated code.  SelectedOfficerIds does store the selected id's.

```
<select id="multiple" asp-for="SelectedOfficerIds" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Officer">    
</select>
```

I am posting to two different databases (1 record should go to SecurityLog, and multiple to SecurityLogOfficer), but since I am calling savechanes() twice it is actually posting multiple records to the SecurityLog db and on the second for loop save I receive an error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SecurityLogOfficer' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

```
_context.SecurityLog.Add(SecurityLog);
//We need to ensure we have the ID of the newly posted event
_context.SaveChanges();

int tempSecurityLogID = SecurityLog.ID;

for (int i = 0; i < SelectedOfficerIds.Length; i++)
{                
     SecurityLogOfficer.SecurityLogID = tempSecurityLogID;
     SecurityLog = null;

     SecurityLogOfficer.OfficerID = SelectedOfficerIds[i];
     _context.SecurityLogOfficer.Add(SecurityLogOfficer);                
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}            

Message = "Entry added successfully!";
```

Is there a way to clear out _context for SecurityLog so I only post once and how can I address the identity_insert issue? The db, SecurityLogOfficer, already has identity insert on.

**Update 1/9/2020**

@XingZou - Thank you for the quick reply.  I attempted to implement your steps and everything worked out perfectly!!!

I do have one additional question if you don't mind?  I am attempting to get a list of the selected values on the Edit Page and cannot set the values.  This is what I tried so far...

**Here is my Edit Page Model...**

```
[BindProperty] 
public MultiSelectList GetExistingSelectedOfficerIds { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
    var i = _context.SecurityLogOfficer.Where(a => a.SecurityLogID == SecurityLog.ID);

        SecurityLogOfficers.AddRange(i);

        int[] GetExistingSelectedOfficerIds = new int[SecurityLogOfficers.Count];

        int itemCount = 0;
        foreach (var item in SecurityLogOfficers)
        {                
            GetExistingSelectedOfficerIds[itemCount] = item.OfficerID;
            itemCount++;
        }

        return Page();
}
```

**Here is my Edit razor page...**

```
<select id="multiple" asp-for= "GetExistingSelectedOfficerIds" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Officer">
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="GetExistingSelectedOfficerIds" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Comment: Could you post your code that you are using to read data from select list? Thanks.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is at the top of the page already.  Maybe I am misunderstanding?

Comment: what is the relationship between SecurityLog and Officer?One-to-many or many-to many?The `asp-for="SecurityLog.Officer"` is useless since you are selecting list of officer ID

Comment: There is no direct relationship between SecurityLog and Officer.  There is a one-to-many relationship between SecurityLog and SecurityLogOfficer and a many-to-one relationship between SecurityLogOfficer and Officer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the dropdown list to a list of int instead of object.

In PageModel, add a new property which stores all selected Ids:

```
[BindProperty]
public int[] SelectedOfficerIds { get; set; }
```

On Razor Pages，bind the multiple select to `SelectedOfficerIds`

```
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="SecurityLog.EventDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="SecurityLog.EventDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="SecurityLog.EventDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Officers</label>
        <select id="multiple" asp-for="SelectedOfficerIds" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Officer">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

When you submit form, you will get new Officer ID list of the SecurityLog in you post handler.

**Update 1/9/2020**

> There is no direct relationship between SecurityLog and Officer. There is a one-to-many relationship between SecurityLog and SecurityLogOfficer and a many-to-one relationship between SecurityLogOfficer and Officer.

From you description, it is [many-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) between `SecurityLog` and `Officer`.
1.Remove the `ID` of `SecurityLogOfficer`,it uses composite key now

```
public class SecurityLogOfficer
{
    public int SecurityLogID { get; set; }
    public SecurityLog SecurityLog { get; set; }

    public int OfficerID { get; set; }
    public Officer Officer { get; set; }
}
public class Officer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //other properties

    public List<SecurityLogOfficer> SecurityLogOfficers { get; set; }
}

public class SecurityLog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //other properties

    public virtual List<SecurityLogOfficer> SecurityLogOfficers { get; set; }
}
```

2.Configure many-to-many relationship like below.

```
public class RazorpagesCoreContext : DbContext
{
    public RazorpagesCoreContext (DbContextOptions<RazorpagesCoreContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }


    public DbSet<Officer> Officer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SecurityLog> SecurityLog { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SecurityLogOfficer> SecurityLogOfficer { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SecurityLogOfficer>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.SecurityLogID, t.OfficerID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SecurityLogOfficer>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.SecurityLog)
            .WithMany(p => p.SecurityLogOfficers)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.SecurityLogID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SecurityLogOfficer>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Officer)
            .WithMany(t => t.SecurityLogOfficers)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.OfficerID);
    }
}
```

3.Add migrations and Update database.

> Is there a way to clear out _context for SecurityLog so I only post once

4.In your PageModel, save data like below

```
[BindProperty]
public SecurityLog SecurityLog { get; set; }

public List<SecurityLogOfficer> SecurityLogOfficers { get; set; } = new List<SecurityLogOfficer>();

[BindProperty]
public int[] SelectedOfficerIds { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        _context.SecurityLog.Add(SecurityLog);
        foreach (var id in SelectedOfficerIds)
        {
            var item = new SecurityLogOfficer()
            {
                SecurityLog = SecurityLog,
                Officer = await _context.Officer.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.ID == id),
            };
            SecurityLogOfficers.Add(item);
        }
        _context.SecurityLogOfficer.AddRange(SecurityLogOfficers);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

**Update 1/10/2020**

To get multiple selected values in Edit Page, use below code before `return Page()` in get handler

```
ViewData["Officer"] = new MultiSelectList(_context.Officers.Where(a => a.Active == "Y"), "ID", "FullName", GetExistingSelectedOfficerIds);
```

Comment: I edited your answer with updated code and questions but I am awaiting peer review approval.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @RobC I just rejected your edit, if you want to update your own code and pose a question you can do so by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59631459/edit) your question

Comment: Sorry about that... @XingZou I updated my original question.

Comment: @Rob C I think what you want is just a many-to-many relationship in ef core.I update my answer.

Comment: @Xing Zou - Your code worked perfectly!  Thank you very much!  I did have 1 additional follow-up question that I added to the original question if you don't mind.  (Update 1/9/2020).  I really appreciate your help as I just started learning about razor pages a few months ago.

Comment: @Rob C just use `ViewData["Officer"] = new MultiSelectList(_context.Officers.Where(a => a.Active == "Y"), "ID", "FullName", GetExistingSelectedOfficerIds);` in the get handler

Comment: @Xing Zou - Thank you!  Completely missed setting the selectedvalues in the MultiSelectList that is being assigned to ViewData.  I was close, but appreciate your help.  Next I am going to try and get a list of comma separated Officer Names to display on the index page.  This may be a little tricky as there is no field in SecurityLog that directly ties to Officer.

Comment: @Rob C If you have resolved current problem in this thread.could you accept the answer?If you have any other problems, you could open a new thread.

Comment: @XingZou - I have been working to display a list of concatenated officers on the index page and have created a new question but I can't seem to get any helpful response.  Are you able to assist?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843281/how-do-i-display-a-concatenated-list-from-a-model-in-another-models-page-model

Comment: @XingZou - I have another question that I posted with a bounty.  If you get a moment, would you mind checking it out?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987588/how-do-i-search-and-sort-a-list-of-concatenated-names-coming-from-another-page-m

Answer (score 0):

You did not share your complete Create pagemodel. In it, do you have something such as the following:

```
public MultiSelectList Officer { get; set; }
```

I believe you will be able to populate that with the Officer's information from the Officer model.

Comment: Based on the suggested answer, I am now using       
    public int[] SelectedOfficerIds { get; set; }