# How do I display a concatenated list from a model in another model's page model?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In my main index page, I would like to display a list of Officers in the Officer's Name column.  i.e. Tommy Bahamas, Clinton K, etc...

I am having difficulty because the Officer and SecurityLogOfficer table are not a part of my SecurityLog model on the index page.

**SecurityLog Index Page**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SecurityLog)
    {
    <tr>
        <td style="width:4% !important">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td style="width:5% !important">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventDate)
        </td>


        <td style="width:5% !important">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OfficerList)
        </td>
}
```

I created a class, OfficerList, to return a list of comma separated Officers but I am having trouble displaying this on the SecurityLog index page.

```
public class OfficerList : SecurityLog
{
    private readonly SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext _context;

    public OfficerList(SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<string> GetOfficerList()
    {
        List<string> OfficerIDs = new List<string>();

        //use the syntax .ToList() to convert object read from db to list to avoid being re-read again
        var SecLog = _context.SecurityLog.ToList();
        var SecLogOfficer = _context.SecurityLogOfficer.ToList();
        var Officer = _context.Officer.ToList();


        int rowID;

        //string[] OfficerIDs = new string[100];
        rowID = 0;

        foreach (SecurityLog sl in SecLog)
        {
            foreach (SecurityLogOfficer slo in SecLogOfficer.Where(slo => slo.SecurityLogID == sl.ID))
            {
                if (OfficerIDs[rowID] == null)
                {
                    OfficerIDs[rowID] = slo.Officer.FullName + ", ";
                }
                else
                {
                    OfficerIDs[rowID] = OfficerIDs[rowID] + slo.Officer.FullName + ", ";
                }
            }

            rowID++;
        }

        return OfficerIDs;

    }

}
```

This is where I would like to display the concatenated list...

[image]

**And here is my database schema and sample results**

[image: Sql Database Schema]

Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I am having an issue retrieving a list of concatenated names in my SecurityLog Model.

```
public class SecurityLog
{
    private readonly SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext _context;

    public SecurityLog(SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

   ......

    public List<string> OfficerList
    {            
        get
        {                                
            var officerList = new OfficerList(_context);                

            return officerList.GetOfficerList();
        }
    }


 }
```

**Modified OfficerList class**

```
public class OfficerList : SecurityLog
{
private readonly SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext _context;

public OfficerList(SecurityCoreContext context) : base(context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public List<string> GetOfficerList()
{
    List<string> OfficerIDs = new List<string>();

    //use the syntax .ToList() to convert object read from db to list to avoid being re-read again
    var SecLog = _context.SecurityLog.ToList();
    var SecLogOfficer = _context.SecurityLogOfficer.ToList();
    var Officer = _context.Officer.ToList();


    int rowID;

    //string[] OfficerIDs = new string[100];
    rowID = 0;

    foreach (SecurityLog sl in SecLog)
    {
        foreach (SecurityLogOfficer slo in SecLogOfficer.Where(slo => slo.SecurityLogID == sl.ID))
        {
            if (OfficerIDs[rowID] == null)
            {
                OfficerIDs[rowID] = slo.Officer.FullName + ", ";
            }
            else
            {
                OfficerIDs[rowID] = OfficerIDs[rowID] + slo.Officer.FullName + ", ";
            }
        }

        rowID++;
    }

    return OfficerIDs;

}
```

}

My _context for SecurityLog is saying that it is null.

> SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be
>   called on Null values.
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_DateTime()
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetDateTime(int i)
>   lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext ,
>   int[] , ResultCoordinator )
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable+Enumerator.MoveNext()
>   System.Collections.Generic.List..ctor(IEnumerable collection)
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable source)
>   SecurityCore.Models.OfficerList.GetOfficerList() in OfficerList.cs
>   +
>               var SecLog = _context.SecurityLog.ToList(); SecurityCore.Models.SecurityLog.get_OfficerList() in SecurityLog.cs
>   +
>                   return officerList.GetOfficerList(); Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ExpressionMetadataProvider+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.g__modelAccessor|0(object container)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExplorer.get_Model()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.TemplateBuilder..ctor(IViewEngine
>   viewEngine, IViewBufferScope bufferScope, ViewContext viewContext,
>   ViewDataDictionary viewData, ModelExplorer modelExplorer, string
>   htmlFieldName, string templateName, bool readOnly, object
>   additionalViewData)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.GenerateDisplay(ModelExplorer
>   modelExplorer, string htmlFieldName, string templateName, object
>   additionalViewData)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.DisplayFor(Expression> expression, string templateName, string htmlFieldName,
>   object additionalViewData)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperDisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression> expression)
>   SecurityCore.Pages.SecurityLogs.Pages_SecurityLogs_Index.ExecuteAsync()
>   in Index.cshtml
>   +
>                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OfficerList) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
>   page, ViewContext context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
>   page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
>   viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
>   viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next,
>   Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
>   bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
>   isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
>   next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
>   isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
>   endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

**UPDATE - ADDING RELATIONSHIPS**

```
public class SecurityCoreContext : DbContext
{
    public SecurityCoreContext (DbContextOptions<SecurityCoreContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SecurityCore.Models.SecurityLog> SecurityLog { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SecurityCore.Models.Entity> Entity { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SecurityCore.Models.Location> Location { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SecurityCore.Models.ShiftRange> ShiftRange { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SecurityCore.Models.EventType> EventType { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SecurityCore.Models.SecurityLogOfficer> SecurityLogOfficer { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SecurityCore.Models.Officer> Officer { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SecurityLogOfficer>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.SecurityLogID, t.OfficerID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SecurityLogOfficer>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.SecurityLog)
            .WithMany(p => p.SecurityLogOfficers)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.SecurityLogID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SecurityLogOfficer>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Officer)
            .WithMany(t => t.SecurityLogOfficers)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.OfficerID);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 1/23/2020**

I attempted to update the code based on the below answer and I think this is really close to being solved, however; inside of the OfficerList class there is not currently a value for SecLog b/c there is no data on page load until the search button is clicked.

```
 OfficerList officerList = new OfficerList();
 OfficerLists = officerList.GetOfficerList(_context);

 SecurityLog = await PaginatedList<SecurityLog>.CreateAsync(sort
    .Include(a => a.Entity)
    .Include(b => b.EventType)
    .Include(c => c.Location)
    .Include(d => d.ShiftRange)
    .Include(e => e.Officer)
    .AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, pageSize);
```

**This is null when going to OfficerList class**

```
var SecLog = _context.SecurityLog.ToList();
```

> > SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
> >     Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()
> >     Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_DateTime()
> >     Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetDateTime(int i)
> >     lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext ,
> >     int[] , ResultCoordinator )
> >     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable+Enumerator.MoveNext()
> >     System.Collections.Generic.List..ctor(IEnumerable collection)
> >     System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable source)
> >     SecurityCore.Models.OfficerList.GetOfficerList(SecurityCoreContext
> >     _context) in OfficerList.cs
> >     +
> >                 var SecLog = _context.SecurityLog.ToList(); SecurityCore.Pages.SecurityLogs.IndexModel.OnGetAsync(string
> >     sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, Nullable
> >     pageIndex, string entitySelect, string entityFilter, DateTime
> >     dateBegin, DateTime dateBeginSelect, DateTime dateEnd, DateTime
> >     dateEndSelect) in Index.cshtml.cs
> >     +
> >                     OfficerLists = officerList.GetOfficerList(_context);

Is there a way in the OfficerList class to not loop through SecurityLog in the foreach and somehow pass in the ID of the SecurityLog as a second parameter to OfficerList( along with _context)?

[image]

Comment: so... for one SecurityLogId there can be many OfficerID is it correct?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: then you would be having `item.OfficerList`  with all the officer within the SecurityLogId, then just iterate on  `item.OfficerList` collection and display all the officer.

Comment: I will have to try that still but I realized that I am having an issue populating the list of concatenated names within the SecurityLog Model.  I have updated my code and provided the null error being returned.

Comment: Do you have a proper relationship with the entity? or you can make a sample and post it on github and share the link here so people can help you out

Comment: @ArvindMaurya - I have added the relationships from the context file.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you have used dependency injection multiple times in the OfficeList and SecurityLog classes. This should be the main cause of the error

I suggest that you only need to use dependency injection in the PageModel, pass _context as a parameter to the GetOfficerList method, and I don't think you need to let the OfficeList inherit the SecurityLog class.

After you return the OfficeIDs collection, use OfficerLists Field in the PageModel to store the collection, and store the SecurityLog data collection to the SecurityLog Field.

At the same time I found some errors in your GetOfficerList method. You can directly refer to the following code for testing.

**PageModel:**

```
public class HomeModel : PageModel
{ 
    private readonly SecurityCoreContext _context;
    public HomeModel(SecurityCoreContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<string> OfficerLists { get; set; }
    public IList<SecurityLog> SecurityLog { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
     {
        OfficerList officerList = new OfficerList();
        OfficerLists = officerList.GetOfficerList(_context);
        SecurityLog = await _context.SecurityLog.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        return Page();
    }
}
```

**OfficerList.cs**

```
public class OfficerList
{
    public List<string> GetOfficerList(SecurityCoreContext _context)
    {
        List<string> OfficerIDs = new List<string>();

        //use the syntax .ToList() to convert object read from db to list to avoid being re-read again
        var SecLog = _context.SecurityLog.ToList();
        var SecLogOfficer = _context.SecurityLogOfficer.ToList();
        var Officer = _context.Officer.ToList();

        int rowID;
        rowID = 0;
        foreach (SecurityLog sl in SecLog)
        {
            int count = SecLogOfficer.Where(slo => slo.SecurityLogID == sl.ID).Count();
            if (count > 0)
            {
                OfficerIDs.Add("");
            }
            foreach (SecurityLogOfficer slo in SecLogOfficer.Where(slo => slo.SecurityLogID == sl.ID))
            {
                OfficerIDs[rowID] = OfficerIDs[rowID] + slo.Officer.FirstName + ", ";
            }
            if (count > 0)
            {
                OfficerIDs[rowID] = OfficerIDs[rowID].Substring(0, OfficerIDs[rowID].Length - 2);
            }
            rowID++;
        } 
        return OfficerIDs;

    }
}
```

**Page:**

```
@page
@model WebApplication_core_razorpage.Pages.HomeModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var i = 0;
}

<h1>Home</h1>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model.SecurityLog)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="width:4% !important">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
            </td>
            <td style="width:5% !important">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventDate)
            </td>

            <td style="width:5% !important">
                @Model.OfficerLists[i]
            </td>
        </tr>
        i++;
    }

</table>
```

Here is the result of this demo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz2LA.png

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  This is close to working I believe but I am running into an issue.  If you don't mind, can you please look at my update starting with, 'UPDATE 1/23/2020'?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that pass id as a parameter to the OfficeList method is a good way, because you need to get all the names corresponding to each SecurityLog, passing parameters will be an unnecessary operation.                                        
If you are concerned about data mismatches, you can sort them to make sure they correspond.Or you receive it via List<object> instead of List<string>.

Comment: I was able to take your suggested answer and tailor it to fit my solution.  However, since I have paging, sorting and searching also in my project, the sorting and searching does not work for the just officerlist.  I have posted my code in the below answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to modify's @Yongqing Yu suggested code to get the officer list to display correctly.  I decided to pass the id to the OfficerList class and the sorting is setup so that I get the correct officer list for each row.

I did not post this logic originally but I have sort, search and paging that I was able to implement based on Microsoft's Contoso University's demo.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1

With the newly implemented code, the sorting and filtering no longer works for officer list.  Everything else works as desired.

**How can I address the sorting and searching in my current code below?
and more specifically... how can I read (iterate) through the list of OfficerIDs and search for the string value of each list item (concatenated officer list row)?**

```
foreach (SecurityLog secLog in SecurityLog)
        {
            secLogCopy = secLog;

            OfficerLists = officerList.GetOfficerList(_context, secLog, rowID, OfficerIDs);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                sort = sort.Where(s => OfficerIDs.ToString().Contains(searchString));
            }
            rowID++;
        }
```

**PageModel:**

```
namespace SecurityCore.Pages.SecurityLogs
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext _context;

        public IndexModel(SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public string EventDateSort { get; set; }
        public string EventStartSort { get; set; }
        public string EventEndSort { get; set; }
        public string ContactNameSort { get; set; }
        public string EventTypeSort { get; set; }
        public string ShiftRangeSort { get; set; }

        public string CurrentSort { get; set; }
        public string IDSort { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public Nullable<DateTime> DateEnd { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public Nullable<DateTime> DateBegin { get; set; }
        public Entity Entity { get; set; }


        public PaginatedList<SecurityLog> SecurityLog { get; set; }
        public List<secLog> SecurityLogOfficers { get; set; } = new List<secLog>();
        public List<string> OfficerLists { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public OfficerList officerList { get; set; } = new OfficerList();
        [BindProperty]
        public List<string> OfficerIDs { get; set; } = new List<string>();







    public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageIndex,
                                 string entitySelect, string entityFilter, DateTime dateBegin, DateTime dateBeginSelect, DateTime dateEnd, DateTime dateEndSelect)
    {
        selectedEntity = new SelectList(_context.Entity.Where(a => a.Active == "Y"), "Name", "Name");

        CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        IDSort = sortOrder == "ID" ? "ID_Desc" : "ID";
        EventDateSort = sortOrder == "EventDate" ? "EventDate_Desc" : "EventDate";
        ContactNameSort = sortOrder == "ContactName" ? "ContactName_Desc" : "ContactName";
        EventTypeSort = sortOrder == "EventType" ? "EventType_Desc" : "EventType";
        ShiftRangeSort = sortOrder == "ShiftRange" ? "ShiftRange_Desc" : "ShiftRange";            
        OfficerNameSort = sortOrder == "OfficerName" ? "OfficerName_Desc" : "OfficerName";


        IQueryable<SecurityLog> sort = from s in _context.SecurityLog select s;


        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "ID_Desc":
                sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.ID);
                break;
            case "ID":
                sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.ID);
                break;
            case "EventDate":
                sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.EventDate);
                break;                
            case "ShiftRange":
                sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.ShiftRange.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                break;
            case "ShiftRange_Desc":
                sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.ShiftRange.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                break;
            case "EventType":
                sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.EventType.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                break;
            case "EventType_Desc":
                sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.EventType.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                break;                
            case "OfficerName":                    
                sort = sort.OrderBy(s => officerList.ToString()).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                break;
            case "OfficerName_Desc":                    
                sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => officerList.ToString()).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                break;
            default:
                sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.EventDate);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 5;





        SecurityLog = await PaginatedList<SecurityLog>.CreateAsync(sort
        .Include(a => a.Entity)
        .Include(b => b.EventType)
        .Include(c => c.Location)
        .Include(d => d.ShiftRange)
        .Include(e => e.Officer)                                    
        .AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, pageSize);



        int rowID;
        rowID = 0;


        foreach (SecurityLog secLog in SecurityLog)
        {
            secLogCopy = secLog;
            OfficerLists = officerList.GetOfficerList(_context, secLog, rowID, OfficerIDs);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                sort = sort.Where(s => OfficerIDs.ToString().Contains(searchString));
            }
            rowID++;
        }



        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {                                                

            sort = sort.Where(s => s.Narrative.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.RecordLocked.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.ContactName.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.Location.Name.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.EventType.Name.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.ShiftRange.Name.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.ID.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                                || s.SubjectFirst.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.SubjectLast.Contains(searchString));                                    
        }

    }

}
```

}

**OfficerList.cs**

```
public class OfficerList
{
    public List<string> GetOfficerList(SecurityCoreContext _context, SecurityLog secLog, int rowID, List<string> OfficerIDs)
    {            

        int CurrentID = secLog.ID;

        var SecLogOfficer = _context.SecurityLogOfficer.ToList();
        var Officer = _context.Officer.ToList();


        int count = SecLogOfficer.Where(slo => slo.SecurityLogID == CurrentID).Count();

        if (count >= 0)
        {
            OfficerIDs.Add("");
        }
        foreach (secLog slo in SecLogOfficer.Where(slo => slo.SecurityLogID == CurrentID))
        {
            OfficerIDs[rowID] = OfficerIDs[rowID] + slo.Officer.FullName + ", ";
        }
        if (count > 0)
        {
            OfficerIDs[rowID] = OfficerIDs[rowID].Substring(0, OfficerIDs[rowID].Length - 2);
        }


        return OfficerIDs;

    }

}
```

**Page:**

```
@page
@model WebApplication_core_razorpage.Pages.HomeModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var i = 0;
}

<h1>Home</h1>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model.SecurityLog)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="width:4% !important">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
            </td>
            <td style="width:5% !important">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventDate)
            </td>

            <td style="width:5% !important">
                @Model.OfficerLists[i]
            </td>
        </tr>
        i++;
    }

</table>
```

**PaginatedList.cs**

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }        

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }


    public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

    public bool ShowFirst
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex != 1);
        }
    }

    public bool ShowLast
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex != TotalPages);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(
        IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip(
            (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```